# C# memory allocation when uploading a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Question somewhat related to uploading a file in MVC.

How is the memory allocated when uploading a file?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(string qqfile)
    {
            var stream = Request.InputStream;
```

Suppose one is uploading a 100 MB file, what happenes once `Request.InputStream` receives it?

EDIT:

What happens to the stream and `Request.InputStream` when processing exits `ActionResult`?

- Where is stream stored? memory allocation?
- When is it disposed? When is Request.InputStream disposed?
- if I store a stream in a variable where is it saved to?
- what happens to "stream" variable once action results exits?
- what does variable "stream" hold?, a reference/pointer to
  Request.InputStream? or a "full" copy of bytes (suppose 100MB)?

Comment: In the provided code there is nothing being read and no memory is needed.

Comment: can you please elaborate? doesn't that 100MB file get loaded into a stream variable?

Comment: No, a stream is just a stream. It can transport data but not store it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Stream is designed to also allow reading from a data source while not all data has been received yet. That is the case with the `Request.InputStream`. Others, like the `MemoryStream`, directly wrap an in-memory buffer.

Where exactly the data is stored depends on the type of stream. There is a buffer on the Socket level where data may be kept until it is read, or perhaps IIS buffers it for you.

The buffer is disposed of when you (or .NET, in this case) dispose the Stream, or when the Garbage Collector does this for you. The socket layer of course only deallocates its buffer once the connetion is closed - disposing the stream does not always dispose the underlying buffer.

The streams are designed so you can work with just that - a `Stream` of data - without having to worry about the underlying buffers. The general rule for who is responsible for disposing a stream is: You create it? You dispose it.

In response to your edits: if you store the stream in a variable, for instance in the ASP.NET session, .NET will dispose of the stream anyway once the `Request` object is no longer needed. Your variable will still contain a reference to that stream, but reading from it will throw an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Pay attention to the difference between a `Stream` and a buffer - a `Stream` provides read and/or write access to a buffer of any kind - even a virtual buffer 'containing' data that has not been received yet. An attempt to read from that buffer will block the current thread until (some of) the data has been received (or until an error has occurred).

And, to complete the confusion, you can have a stream which reads from multiple buffers, multiple streams reading from the same buffer, and streams wrapping streams.

Comment: so if I understand correctly: "A Stream is designed to also allow reading from a data source while not all data has been received yet" => how does that work once I'm in my Action? => isn't my "stream" fully read by then? When I debug I see at "var stream=" that stream is fully loaded.  Request.InputStream gets a stream of data (suppose 100MB) => this stream is stored either in IIS or .NET?. When ActionResult finished Request.InputStream is set to null and allocated buffer is released/disposed? thanks

Comment: The stream provides access to data stored either in the socket layer, but IIS could decide to buffer this for you - I don't know IIS that well. When .NET decides you're done with the request, .NET will dispose the stream.

Comment: If you ignore the 100MB completely without reading it, but the client does stay connected and issues another request on the same connection after sending it, .NET will read and dispose of that 100MB before you can access the next request. Hope that helps in clearing things up for you.

Comment: If you read from a stream faster than the data can be received on the socket, the stream will block execution on that thread until it can read additional data.